# MYSQL how to join two rows in one

Tags: mysql

I have a table in which im recording the opening and closing times of different stores. This is the example:

[image]

As you can see the opening and closing times are in different rows. I need to put everything in the same row and also create a new column in the end that will calculate the number of hours between the WORKSTATION_OPEN and the WORKSTATION CLOSE. Basically what I'm trying to achieve is this:

[image]

Comment: this is called a pivot query, and mysql doesn't directly support them. since you're only dealing with a 1->2 row->col translation, the query won't be too ugly, but if you start adding more conditions, the query will uglify very quickly.

Comment: You can JOIN the table to itself, as if you're selecting from two different tables, but as Marc said, this gets ugly and it also adversely affects performance. The other option is to select both rows and manipulate the result in whatever language you're using to present it.

Comment: I see. Well the idea was to avoid having to manipulate this in PHP. I would like to have all the information already prepared in the query itself. So in this current scenario what is the best option to get the number of hours between the WORKSTATION_OPEN and the WORKSTATION_CLOSE?

Comment: But why? PHP is so much better at handling issues of data display!

Answer (score 0):

you join the table to itself, on rtl_log_id i guess...

```
select
    opentimes.datetime as open,
    closetimes.datetime as close,
    closetimes.datetime-opentimes.datetime as duration 
from
    (...) as opetimes,(...) as closetimes
where
    opentimes.trans_typecode=OPEN 
    and closetimes.trans_typecode=CLOSE 
    and opentimes.rtl_log_id=close_times.rtl_log_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably group by rt_log_id or business_day and do a [`group concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) on the datetime.

Then you process that combined string outside mysql.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff24a6/2